# Not able to access docker daemon api from docker container

Tags: networking, docker, vagrant, virtualbox

I have vagrant box running with docker daemon and on same box I have a docker container running.

From docker container, I am trying to curl `http://<IP-of-virtualbox>:2375/version` and it's not able to connect. Getting the message `connection refused`

But from host machine I can curl `http://<IP-of-virtualbox>:2375/version`, not only from container.

Answer (score 0):

Your docker container doesn't know how to get to the `<IP-of-virtualbox-machine>`.  The containers run a different subnet, if you are using one of the latest versions of Docker it should be the same subnet as your `docker0` interface on the VirtualBox VM where you are running the docker daemon.

For example for this docker daemon VirtualBox VM:

```
docker@default:~$ ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          inet addr:A.B.C.D  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: ffff::ff:ffff:ffff:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1091 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:26832 (26.2 KiB)  TX bytes:2734357 (2.6 MiB)
```

and this container:

```
user@45b26c832418:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
          inet addr:A.B.C.E  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: ffff::ff:ffff:ffff:1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:926 (926.0 B)  TX bytes:598 (598.0 B)
```

you can run the following from the container:

```
curl http://A.B.C.D:2375/status
```

Comment: I have same setup on 2 different boxes. One is Ubuntu and one is Fedora. On Ubuntu it's working perfectly but not on Fedora box.

Comment: Yes, I am using virtual box IP address in container running on ubuntu machine and I can curl.

Comment: What about your iptables? in both containers? are they the same?